# Move local copy of git in Github for Mac

Tags: macos, git, github

I have cloned the source of a git repository to `/path1/foo/`, but I want move the local copy to a new location say `/path2/foo/`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working solution:

1. Clone foo from github to /path2/foo/ in Github for Mac
2. If local version is different from the latest at github, move /path1/foo/ to /path2/foo/

Comment: In short: a repository lives in a plain old directory and doesn't know or expect or require anything at all about where it sits in the filesystem. Move it, rename it, whatever. git will track changes INSIDE the repo directory, but not changes TO the repo directory itself.

Answer (score 5):

In Terminal:

```
mv /path1/foo /path2/foo
```

Or, in Finder: drag and drop the git repo folder from one place to another.

Comment: Then it gets deleted form Github

Answer (score 0):

Open bash terminal and run this command:

`mv .* YOUR-NEW-LOCATION-OF-DIRECTORY`

Replace `YOUR-NEW-LOCATION-OF-DIRECTORY` with your new destination directory and this command will move all hidden files/folders such as `.git`.

Comment: 10 year after an answer was accepted, how is this better?